# How to change the font, size, and wrapping of a tooltip?

Tags: macos, cocoa

I've got a cell-based `NSTableView` and I'm setting up tooltips for the rows using the standard `NSTableViewDelegate` method for that:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView toolTipForCell:(NSCell *)aCell rect:(NSRectPointer)rect tableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex mouseLocation:(NSPoint)mouseLocation
{
    if (aTableView == scriptBlocksTableView)
    {
        std::vector<SLiMEidosBlock*> &scriptBlocks = sim->script_blocks_;
        int scriptBlockCount = (int)scriptBlocks.size();

        if (rowIndex < scriptBlockCount)
        {
            SLiMEidosBlock *scriptBlock = scriptBlocks[rowIndex];
            const char *script_string = scriptBlock->compound_statement_node_->token_->token_string_.c_str();
            NSString *ns_script_string = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:script_string];

            // change whitespace to non-breaking spaces; we want to force AppKit not to wrap code
            ns_script_string = [ns_script_string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@" "];        // second string is an &nbsp;
            ns_script_string = [ns_script_string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\t" withString:@"   "];     // second string is three &nbsp;s

            return ns_script_string;
        }
    }

    return nil;
}
```

This is Objective-C++ code, as it happens, but that is not important to the question.  The tooltip I want to display is a small snippet of code.  I'd like it to display in a small monospace font (Monaco 9?), and I'd like the lines not to wrap.  As you can see, I'm replacing spaces and tabs with non-breaking spaces here to try to prevent line-wrapping, and that works, but only up to a point.  If a line is too long, AppKit will force a wrap even though there is no valid wrap point; it just enforces a maximum tooltip width no matter what.

I can't find any way to change the font/size of tooltips, or to force them not to wrap.  I did find [this ancient article](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20061107125819464) about defaults that affect tooltips; I didn't even try those, since an app-wide default is not acceptable (since my app has other tooltips that I want to behave normally).  This article does suggest that the needed machinery is present under the hood in AppKit; I just need an API.

I suspect the answer is "sorry, you're out of luck".  In that event, does anybody have any good custom tooltip display code, presumably using a popup or a borderless window or some such, that they would be willing to share?  Ideally it would mimic the appearance and behavior of standard Cocoa tooltips, but add this sort of configurability.  Or does anybody have an alternative solution?

Comment: Is the tooltip the same as the cell content but just not truncated? That is, are you looking for an expansion tooltip? Or, even if it's not the same, perhaps a custom cell that does custom sizing and drawing of an expansion tooltip will work.

Comment: No, the tooltip is different from what is shown in the table row.